# Multi query and transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I do some treatment on many data, so i do a loop.

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void processPayment(List<Long> paymentsId, PaymentModeEnum paymentMode) throws ProcessPaymentException{
   ...
   processCreditCardPayment(payments);
}

private void processCreditCardPayment(List<Payment> payments) throws ProcessPaymentException {
    for (Payment payment : payments) {

         try {
              //save to db
         }catch (ProcessPaymentException ppe) {
         }

    }
}
```

ProcessPaymentException extends Exception

If I loop on 10 item, on the last one, error happen.
Everything is rollbacked (all my item) or only the one in error?

Comment: You can easily test the behavior. That being said the answer depends on the implementation of `save to db`

Comment: only save method from spring data repository.

Answer (score 0):

In this case nothing would be rolled back. It is because you caught the exception and it didn't pass Spring transaction boundary.

[Read here in Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-rolling-back):

> The recommended way to indicate to the Spring Framework’s transaction
>   infrastructure that a transaction’s work is to be rolled back is to
>   throw an Exception from code that is currently executing in the
>   context of a transaction. The Spring Framework’s transaction
>   infrastructure code will catch any unhandled Exception as it bubbles
>   up the call stack, and make a determination whether to mark the
>   transaction for rollback.